# Convert byte array to image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I used

```
private BitmapImage byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    try
    {               
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        BitmapImage returnImage = new BitmapImage();
        returnImage.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        returnImage.StreamSource = ms;
        returnImage.EndInit();

        return returnImage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method in my application to convert byte array to an image. But it throws "Parameter is not valid" exception.. why it is happening..? Is there any alternative method.??

Comment: which line throws that exception?

Comment: System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
this code throws the mentioned exception...

Comment: @BijoyKJose I know this is a long time ago, but have you found a solution to the issue `"No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found"`. I'm having the same issue at the moment and I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Hi this should be working:

```
    private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            mem.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: I modified my own code snippet and i used yours as well.. but both throws exception "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found" after executing image.EndInit(); any solution for this..?

Comment: is your imageData set? This method works if the bytes are saved first to a stream or if you load a image-file's bytes into memory - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.endinit.aspx

Answer (score 20):

If you have array like this:

```
byte[] byteArrayIn = new byte[] {255, 128, 0, 200};
```

And you want something like:
[image]

Use:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(2, 2, 300, 300,PixelFormats.Indexed8,    BitmapPalettes.Gray256, byteArrayIn, 2);

Image.Source = bitmapSource;
```

In xaml:

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" x:Name="Image"></Image>
```

Comment: Your answer saved my day! Easy to understand just the essence. After 2 hours messing around with Pixelformats and BitmapPalettes it's funny to see how easy it really is.

Answer (score 6):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        var res = of.ShowDialog();
        if (res.HasValue)
        {
            imgPreview.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName));

            var t = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(imgPreview.Source as BitmapSource);
            var d = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName)));
            var s = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(imgPreview.Source);
            var enc = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(new PngBitmapEncoder(), imgPreview.Source);
            //imgPreview2.Source = Utils.ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(enc);
            imgPreview2.Source = Utils.ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage2(enc);
            //var i = 0;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a currect file...");

        }
    }

}
```

/*util.cs*/

```
public class Utils
{
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapEncoder encoder, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        var bitmapSource = imageSource as BitmapSource;

        if (bitmapSource != null)
        {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image)
    {
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        var image = imageSource as BitmapSource;
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(Uri uri)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage(uri);
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(string filepath)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filepath));
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```