# Show image From Database in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Here is what I have so far:

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

      FileDialog filedg = new OpenFileDialog();
      filedg.Filter = "Images (*.jpg,*.png)|*.jpg;*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
      filedg.ShowDialog();
      {
           StrName = filedg.SafeFileName;
           ImageName = filedg.FileName;
           ImageSourceConverter  isc = new ImageSourceConverter();
           UserImage.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, isc.ConvertFromString(ImageName));
      }

      filedg = null;
 }
```

and in XAML :

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding UserImage}" />
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and my save butten :

```
 FileStream fsz = new FileStream(ImageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fsz.Length];
 fsz.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fsz.Length));
 fsz.Close();
 database.Sp_gym(Username.Text.Trim(), UserFamily.Text.Trim(), UserTel.Text.Trim(), UserUsername.Text.Trim(),
      UserPassword.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToByte(UserAge.Text.Trim()), 1, 1, UserCode.Text.Trim(), UserLocation.Text.Trim(), UserHomePhone.Text.Trim(), 
      UserDoreSine.Text.Trim(), UserBazu.Text.Trim(), UserKamar.Text.Trim(), UserGhad.Text.Trim(), UserVazn.Text.Trim(), 1, 1, 1, cAccCreditDate.SelectedDateTime.ToString(),
      " " , UserCodePost.Text.Trim(), cAccCreditDate.SelectedDateTime.ToString() , UserCharge.Text.Trim() ,1, 1 , "" , imgByteArr);          
 database.SaveChanges();
```

And database ofc :
[my results](https://preview.ibb.co/c2zHQo/Untitled_1.jpg)

But still it dont show any images in datagrid .
Where is the problem guys?

Comment: Please add the code for *loading images to DataGrid* to question.

Comment: i added that.do u know what is the problem ?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214884/2928544)

Comment: Provided that imgByteArr, i.e. what you read from the database, contains a valid encoded bitmap frame like a PNG or JPEG, just declare the UserImage property as byte array and pass imgByteArr to it. WPF will automatically perform the conversion to ImageSource.

Comment: Can u give me the code?

Comment: I don't have "the code". If you don't understand what it means to declare a byte array property that you bind to, you should probably start over and learn the basics.