# What is the easiest way to display an image from Byte[]?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a structure containing an image in black and white:

```
public class Img
{
    public int height;
    public int width;
    public byte[] matrix;
}
```

The values containing in matrix are 0 or 255.

What is the best way to display this image in a component using C# WPF?

I've try this :

XAML:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0"
       Stretch="Uniform"
       Source="{Binding Picture, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

C#:

```
public BitmapImage Picture
{
    get
    {
        return _picture;
    }
    private set
    {
        _picture = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Picture");
    }
}

public void Generate()
{
    Img img = CreateImg();
    Picture = LoadImage(img.width, img.height, img.matrix);
}

private BitmapImage LoadImage(int w, int h, byte[] imageData)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        memory.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();
        return bitmapimage;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work:

> "Exception from HRESULT : 0x88982F50"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert byte array to image in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564174/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-wpf)

Comment: I check and that exact code works for me in a project

Comment: I've seen this post, my `LoadImage` starts from this but I have an Exception and wonder if there is a better way due to my image in black/white

Comment: Is `matrix` really a byte array containing an image? Check it by writing to a file and read this as raw in an image viewer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BitmapImage.StreamSource` property only accepts a stream that contains an encoded bitmap buffer, e.g. a PNG or JPEG.

In order to create a `BitmapSource` (the base class of `BitmapImage`) from raw pixel data, you may use the `BitmapSource.Create()` method. Depending on the number of bits per pixel, and the ordering of the alpha and color channels, you would also have to choose an appropriate `PixelFormat`.

Assuming an 8-bit grayscale format, you would create a BitmapSource like this:

```
private BitmapSource LoadImage(int width, int height, byte[] imageData)
{
    var format = PixelFormats.Gray8;
    var stride = (width * format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

    return BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, format, null, imageData, stride);
}
```

Of course you would also have to change the type of your property to `BitmapSource` (which is more flexible anyway, since you can still assign a `BitmapImage`).

```
public BitmapSource Picture { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/6438653):

```
    private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            mem.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }
```