# Is it possible WPF use the MFC OnDraw(CDC* pDC) to render the image?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I am working in a MFC project and I started to migrate the UI to WPF, but I stack on this part,

Is it possible WPF use the MFC `OnDraw(CDC* pDC)` to render the image?

Comment: Probably not practical. [Much of WPF is managed code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx).

Comment: but if i return a bitmap from another function maybe a have a chance, yes?

Comment: @HudsonPH I guess so, draw into a bitmap in memory and then pass that to WPF to render. [See this for some details of getting the bitmap to WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564174/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-wpf)

Comment: thanks, I will check and tomorrow i will give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

WPF and MFC are two separate frameworks with different models even technologies (C++ in MFC and C# in WPF), and they cannot directly invoke each other's class methods. They are designed to work with different languages(C# & C++ respectively).

MFC provides a set of C++ classes and libraries for building Windows applications. It is tightly integrated with the Windows API and relies on the message handling mechanism of Windows.

On the other hand, WPF is designed for use with .NET languages, primarily C#. It uses XAML (eXtensible Application Markup Language) for declarative UI design and provides a rich set of UI controls and data binding capabilities.

If you have existing MFC code that you want to use within a WPF application, you would generally need to rewrite or refactor that code in C# to work with the WPF framework. Direct integration between WPF & MFC is not possible without significant modifications.

That being said, it is possible to use managed extensions for C++ (C++/CLI) to bridge the gap between MFC and .NET, including WPF. C++/CLI allows you to write code that can interoperate with both native C++ (such as MFC) and .NET code. C++ code in MFC is unmanaged code while WPF has managed code in C#. I have not directly worked in such integration, but you can try.

In summary, while MFC does not inherently support C#, and WPF cannot directly invoke MFC class methods, you can rewrite or refactor the MFC code to work with WPF and utilize the features and capabilities of the WPF framework.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT.