# XAML to C# Code: Binding Image to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to bind images in a `ListView` via code behind. The goal is to write this section of code in C #. How does binding in code behind work?
This is my xaml code:

```
<ListView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="MyListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewDataList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Uid="GridViewTest">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1Text}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column2">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding Column2Img}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Column1Text** and **Column2Img** are properties.
I tried something like this:

```
GridView MyGridView = new GridView();

GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Column1Text");
gvc1.Header = "Column1";
MyGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);

System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
img.Height = 50;
img.Width = 50;
img.Source = new Binding("Column2Img");

FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
dt.VisualTree = spFactory;

GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc2.Header = "Column2";
gvc2.CellTemplate = dt;
MyGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);

MyListView.View = MyGridView;
```

But the binding for image in code behind doesn't work.

Comment: Use a Converter on your Binding and you should be fine. But what your Image is? string, byte[], ImageSource, Bitmap? [byte example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/2029607).

Comment: @XAMlMAX image is type of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `Source` property instead of setting it to a `Binding` object directly:

```
img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Column2Img"));
```

But you also need to create an `FrameworkElementFactory` for the `Image` element that you add to `spFactory`:

```
FrameworkElementFactory imgFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
imgFactory.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, 50.0);
imgFactory.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, 50.0);
imgFactory.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Column2Img"));

FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
spFactory.AppendChild(imgFactory);
```

Note that using a `FrameworkElementFactory` is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx.

> The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a `string` or a memory stream using the `Load` method of the `XamlReader` class.

Comment: Thand you! I got an exception: "50" is not a valid value for property "Height" in imgFactory.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, 50);

Comment: Change it to 50.0 or 50d to indicate that it's a double value. I edited my answer.

Comment: the solution with xaml code shows the images in the listview as expected. but not the one with code behind. I create the listview with c# in loaded event of the window.The first column contains the string, as expected, but not the second. Only the type of the binding value can be seen as a string.

Comment: Ok solved. I forgot the line "gvc2.CellTemplate = dt;"