# Selenium screenshot to memory

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot

Is there a way to save a screenshot to memory and then load it into an image control(wpf) without saving it to disk?

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\hello.bmp", OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Thanks¡¡¡

Comment: Why  not just open the file and read the `byte`s?

Comment: The `Screenshot` class has a property called `AsByteArray` which returns the raw array of bytes for the image. You should be able to use that.

Comment: Perfect, works well with `AsByteArray` and them [Convert byte array to image in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564174/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-wpf)